# How do you use "so much" in a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am a non native English speaker. As far as I know, "so much" means a lot of something. However, I heard a conversation that went like this:

*Person 1: "They can clean so much"

Person 2: "Yes, it wasn't like it used to be".*

From hearing the conversation, I assumed that "they can clean so much" means they can't clean the way they used to in the past. Is that correct? Does that mean using "so much" in a sentence can also be when you want to say that a certain quantity is limited?

Comment: The phrase 'so much' can have various meanings depending on context. Maybe the first speaker said "They can _only_ clean so much", meaning that it is only possible to clean an area partially, or less often than was done before?

Comment: Knowing the full context might make a difference, but my initial interpretation of *They can clean so much* is that speaker is saying *They can clean **a great many different types of things*** - probably by way of contrast with how ***few*** different types of things people were able to clean properly in the past (before we had detergents, cheap solvents, vacuum cleaners, ion generators, etc.).